# I would like to add labels in some precise points of the ggplot graph, how can i do it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I built a ggplot, on the x axis I reported the dates and on the y values ​​with the following code:

```r
ggplot() +  
  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=stat),color='blue',) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=fit),color='red',lty=5) + 
  ylab('Values') + xlab('date') + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "week", date_labels = "%d %b %Y") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5,hjust=1))
```

I would like to add labels in some precise points of the graph, how can i do it?
I would like to choose the possession within the graph and the writing

Comment: OP, if you want a specific answer, you'll need to provide an example dataset and at least describe what you want to add where, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `annotate()`.
You can have a look - https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html
and https://ggplot2-book.org/annotations.html
Please add a min rep example for further details.

Comment: thank you very much. The return notes are useful for my case. can i choose the style too? I have to insert the labels in points of a time series, I want to make them quite visible.